# Where is NFS data cached?

Tags: nfs

I mounted an NFS export and started a process that I expected to write a significant amount of data to the shared disk.  The speed of the shared disk was so slow that I killed the process, but IO on the machine exporting the drive stayed high for 90 minutes after that.

Where in the NFS data chain would that data have been cached & what could I have done to stop that from being written to disk?

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting question. It's hard to answer because it's quite variable and depends on:

- what your NFS server is doing. (A NAS appliance is usually going to be quite clever about caching).
- Why your speed was 'so slow'.

In general though - it's entirely normal for a server to cache write operations. RAID write penalty is quite high*, and you can mitigate it substantially by caching and coalescing write operations.

Also generally, it's also incredibly difficult to 'screw up' or otherwise abort pending writes from a cache, because there's all sorts of unpleasant consequences to doing that. (like data corruption).

If IO on the exporting machine was high, that might be a sign of a failing disk - you might have a relatively small amount of data 'in cache' but it's failing and retrying when writing. (Because if it's 'in cache' losing it is not an option, because you've already said you've 'got it').

Which cache it would have been in is hard to guess. There's multiple layers of caching. I wouldn't expect caches to persist for as much as 90m though - data in cache is data that's not persistent, so it's more vulnerable to power failures.

* For each write to a RAID6, the controller must read: Overwrite block, 2 parity blocks, recalculate, and then rewrite all 3 blocks. That means 6 write operations per write. If you group your writes properly, this problem is significantly reduced.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason it's slow is because it's a really old RAID 5 NAS.